# Java Exercise 31: Lower limit and upper limit

Tags: java

I'm having trouble with an exercise.

The instructions are:

> Create a program that asks the user for the first number and the last number and then prints all numbers between those two.

Below is my code.  If the **first** number is **greater** than the **last** number, the program **prints nothing**.

```
System.out.println("First: ");
int first = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
System.out.println("Second: ");
int second = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
int number = first;

while (first <= second) {
    System.out.println(number);
    number = first + 1;
}
```

Comment: This will run for ever. You need to increment number by 1 every time and check `number<=second` or increment first.

Comment: What is your question? As is, your question is unclear. It just seems like a "fix my code for me" post. What exactly is not working? What is the expected and actual output?

Comment: This looks straightforward enough to me @Frakcool.  The input is provided as part of the natural question (that is, for your two inputs, enter 10 and 9 and that'll be enough to invoke the error).

Comment: @Makoto I think I didn't read very carefully then, with your edit it becomes clearer. English isn't my first language so I might have missed it a little

Comment: @clinomaniac:  If/when this gets reopened, you should consider making that an answer to this question.